# $X^n - t$ is irreducible over $k(t)$

Tags: polynomials, rational-functions, irreducible-polynomials

How can I prove (if it's true) that $X^n - t$ is irreducible over $k(t)$, the field of fractions of $k$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Eisenstein's criterion. By Gauss' lemma, $X^n - t$ is irreducible over $k(t)$ iff it's irreducible over $k[t]$. Now, consider $\mathfrak{p} = (t)$. It is prime, and $t \not \in \mathfrak{p}^2$, so $X^n - t$ is irreducible over $k[t]$ by Eisenstein's criterion.

Answer (score 3):

Viewing $X^n-t$ as a polynomial over $k[t]$, this is a [primitive polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_%28ring_theory%29#Formal_statements), because the $\gcd$ of the (non-zero) coefficients $1,-t$ is $1$. Therefore by a [lemma of Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_%28polynomial%29), it will be irreducible over $k(t)$ if and only if it is irreducible over $k[t]$. But over $k[t]$ the polynomial satisfies the [Schönemann-Eisenstein criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) for the irreducible element $t$, hence it is irreducible.

Comment: Why is it necessary to check if the polynomial is primitive ? I thought that it was only necessary if we want to show that $P$ is irreducible over $k[t]$, knowing that it is over $k(t)$.

Comment: @Arnaud: That is right, but then I said "if and only if". The point is, if the polynomial hadn't been primitive, then it would stand no chance of being irreducible over $k[t]$, and it would be necessary to make it primitive before proceeding.

Comment: @Arnaud: And actually there is a special case where a polynomial is irreducible over $k[t]$ while not being irreducible over $k(t)$, namely if it is a constant (w.r.t. $X$) polynomial (therefore _invertible_ in $k(t)$) where the constant is irreducible as element of $k[t]$. That's not the case here of course, it just shows you cannot blindly deduce irreducibility from the other side in either direction.